# Check if a node has a specific child node

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to find out if a DOM node has children nodes that have a certain name

```
$yes = false;
foreach($el->childNodes as $node){
  if($node->nodeName == 'foo'){
    $yes = true;
  }
}
```

Can I do this without iterating over the node list?

There a `hasChildNodes` function but it doesn't accept any node name argument :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$elements = $xpath->query('/parentName/childName');
if ($elements->length) {
    // has child elements
}
```